# Html.BeginForm() with Razor Generator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, custom-controls, helper

I am making a Helper with razor generator to build a cutom control in which there will be two radio buttons (yes/no)
I want to use Html.BeginForm for this.

But can't do it.

Do you know how to do it or another way to do it ?

Thanks.

Edit :

When I put this code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <input type="radio"/>
    <input type="radio"/>
}
```

I get this error

```
'System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for BeginForm and no extension method
'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'could be found
```

Comment: What do you mean you "can't do it"? Is there an error message?

Comment: 'System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for BeginForm and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'could be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a namespacing or reference issue.

First, check to make sure that `System.Web.WebPages` shows up in your project references. Then add

```
@using System.Web.WebPages
```

to the top of your view. If that fixes it, you can move the reference into the web.config per [this answer on the same type of topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808812/problem-recognizing-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-3-razor)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your helper function when your helper functions are located in the App_Code folder.

```
var Html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
var Ajax = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Ajax;
```

Don't forget to include the right namespaces in the file: `@using ....`

Comment: Irritating to have to include these references in each helper method, and have Resharper complain about variable obfuscation etc

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a missing namespace, yes, but not the one mentioned by [eouw0o83hf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636046/263681):

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post your code when you ask a question so we can see what you're doing wrong.  Try this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <input type="radio"/>
        <input type="radio"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and just solved it. I changed version in the web.config file under the views folder.
Here is my previous code

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, **Version=5.0.2.2**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="CMSSol" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and here is my new code

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, **Version=5.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="CMSSol" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```