# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have changed service providers, and since then as soon as i goto www.greptech.co.za i get the above error.

The service provider is using .NET 4.0 and does have the latest MVC3 installed and up to date.

What else can be the issue ? I have googled this, and i have done the above checks. The service provider doesnt know what else is wrong.

I havent changed my Web.config file, for it was working with my old service provider.

Site has been down for a long time now. Please can anyone assist

Here is my web.config file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
      -->
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySqlServer" connectionString="Datasource=431.186.904.538;Port=3306;Database=grep;uid=user;pwd='XXXX';Allow User Variables=true;check parameters=false;logging=true" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>

      <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="support@greptech.co.za">
            <network host="mail.greptech.co.za" userName="support@greptech.co.za" password="XXXX" port="25" />
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="ENV" value="PROD"/>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.web>
        <!--   <customErrors mode="On"/> -->
        <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>

        <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>

       <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
            <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
            <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <clear />
                    <add value="Default.htm" />
                    <add value="Default.asp" />
                    <add value="index.htm" />
                    <add value="index.html" />
                    <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                    <add value="default.aspx" />
                    <add value="index.php" />
                </files>
            </defaultDocument>
              </system.webServer>

      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
    </configuration>
```

Ok, thanks for the reply .. Here is the ~/Views/Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
          <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

      <system.net >
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="support@greptech.co.za">
            <network host="mail.greptech.co.za" userName="support@greptech.co.za" password="XXXX" port="25" />
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>

      <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
      </system.web.webPages.razor>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>

        <!--
            Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
            after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
            MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
            To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
            controller or action.
        -->
        <pages
            validateRequest="false"
            pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
            pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
            userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
          </controls>
        </pages>
      </system.web>

      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

        <handlers>
          <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
          <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I ended up going back to original Service Provider

Comment: This question is vague without any code for review. One thing you can try: set Copy Local to true on the System.web.mvc reference. Also: did you not test your migration before making it live?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: It was working previously on old ISP .. when i migrated, it gives me the above error. I should have tested it :-( before making it live .. I'll will try your suggesion by setting it to true. Thanks, anything else i could try ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have an idea what's going on looking at the debug output - this part doesn't look right:

```
Line 12:   namespace ASP {
Line 13:       using System;
Line 14:       using System.Collections.Generic;
Line 15:       using System.IO;
Line 16:       using System.Linq;
Line 17:       using System.Net;
Line 18:       using System.Web;
Line 19:       using System.Web.Helpers;
Line 20:       using System.Web.Security;
Line 21:       using System.Web.UI;
Line 22:       using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:       using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
Line 24:       using WebMatrix.Data;
Line 25:       using WebMatrix.WebData;
Line 26:       
Line 27:       
Line 28:       public class _Page_index_cshtml : System.Web.WebPages.WebPage {
```

First your page inherits WebPages.WebPage - how did that happen? Then above.. notice the lack of System.Web.Mvc ? That's the reason you also get errors for missing 'BeginForm' and 'Partial' methods, because they are all part of the System.Web.Mvc namespace. 
Here's how a fresh MVC 3 project output looks for me:

```
Line 12:   namespace ASP {
Line 13:       using System;
Line 14:       using System.Collections.Generic;
Line 15:       using System.IO;
Line 16:       using System.Linq;
Line 17:       using System.Net;
Line 18:       using System.Web;
Line 19:       using System.Web.Helpers;
Line 20:       using System.Web.Security;
Line 21:       using System.Web.UI;
Line 22:       using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:       using System.Web.Mvc;
Line 24:       using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Line 25:       using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Line 26:       using System.Web.Routing;
Line 27:       
Line 28:       
Line 29:       public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic> {
```

The config you listed above is perfectly fine. However the config in /Views is what affects the generation of views and my best guess is there's something wrong there. This is the bit that I noticed makes or breaks the view output (namespaces here are directly reflected in the generated code, similar to [Problem recognizing html helpers in asp.net mvc 3 razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808812/problem-recognizing-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc-3-razor) ):

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

At this point it seems like a good idea if you can also add the ~/Views/Web.config in case this is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback .. I have added the ~Views/Web.config file for you to see .. thanks

Comment: I still get the same error when i set the copy local for the dll file to true .. Can you please assist ? thanks

Comment: Not sure if it's the assemblies themselves. Your config file looks all good, however, your views still get compiled without the proper settings. There must be something not set up/missing.
PS: Did a quick test. Removing the config file from its location under ~/Views gives me exactly THE SAME error as yours. Any chance it's not hosted with the rest of the files or inaccessible for some reason? That's the only way I can reproduce your error. Hopefully I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going back to original Service Provider